# Billing cycle, get a date every month (no such Feb 30)

Tags: postgresql

I have a column called `anchor` which is a `timestamp`. I have a row with value of jan 30 2020. I want to compare this to feb 29 2020, and it should give me 1 month. Even though its not 30 days, but feb has no more days after 29. I am trying to bill every month.

Here is my sql fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6906d/2

```
create table subscription (
  id serial,
  anchor timestamp
);

insert into subscription (anchor) values 
('2020-01-30T00:00:00.0Z'),
('2019-01-30T00:00:00.0Z');

select id,
       anchor,
       AGE('2020-02-29T00:00:00.0Z', anchor) as "monthsToFeb29-2020",
       AGE('2019-02-28T00:00:00.0Z', anchor) as "monthsToFeb28-2019"
from subscription;
```

Is it possible to get age in the way I am speaking?

My expected results:

- For age from jan 30 2020 to feb 29 2020 i expect 1.0 month
- For age from jan 30 2020 to feb 28 2019 i expect -11.0 month
- For age from jan 30 2019 to feb 29 2020 i expect 13.0 month
- For age from jan 30 2019 to feb 28 2019 i expect 1.0 month

(this is how momentjs library does it for those node/js guys out there):

```
const moment = require('moment');
moment('Jan 30 2019', 'MMM DD YYYY').diff(moment('Feb 29 2020', 'MMM DD YYYY'), 'months', true) === -13.0
moment('Jan 30 2019', 'MMM DD YYYY').diff(moment('Feb 28 2019', 'MMM DD YYYY'), 'months', true) === -1.0
```

Comment: `For age from jan 30 2020 to feb 2 2020 i expect 1.0 month` here the difference is 3 days but you are expecting 1 month? can you explain the logic for requirement? What i understood if day is greater than anchor date then you are counting it as a month

Comment: Whoops @AkhileshMishra i fixed that, i mean 28th/29th.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
select round(('2/29/2020'::date - '1/30/2020'::date) / 30.0);
 round 
-------
     1

select round(('02/28/2019'::date - '1/30/2020'::date ) / 30.0);
 round 
-------
   -11

select round(('2/29/2020'::date - '1/30/2019'::date) / 30.0);
 round 
-------
    13

select round(('2/28/2019'::date - '01/30/2019'::date) / 30.0);
 round 
-------
     1
```

The date subtraction gives you a integer value of days, then you divide by a 30 day month and round to nearest integer. You could put this in a function and use that.

Comment: Thanks Adrian! This is very nice thank you! I don't think it perfectly matches `moment.diff` but I think this is definitely the basis, thanks for it! Accepted!

Comment: Well moment.diff() does special handling for months/years [diff](https://github.com/moment/moment/pull/571). Not sure I agree with it, but it is what it is.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that! I didn't know of that one. I'll try to mimic that in postgres. As that gives me the correct billing count. Like if I diff Jan 30, 2020 and Feb 29, 2020 it gives me 1. Meaning I should have billed the user twice once at start + the diff.